# É possível utilizar o IGNORE com base em um campo que não é o PK, é apenas um Indice Único?

Tags: php, mysql

Levando em conta a seguinte modelagem:

```
ID INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
PONTO INT (10) NOT NULL UNIQUE
ENDEREÇO INT (10) NOT NULL (FOREIGN KEY)
```

<sub>Onde o campo `ID` é um *Auto Increment*, o campo `PONTO` é um campo com valores únicos (não pode se repetir, como uma PK) e `ENDEREÇO` é uma relação com outra tabela.</sub>

É possível eu utilizar o `IGNORE` com base no campo `PONTO` ou devo torna-lo a `PK`?

Se for possível (utilizar `ignore` com base no `ponto`), utilizar os recursos de *Last Index* do MySQLi e do PDO (no PHP) retornaria o `ID` caso o item já existisse no banco?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não há problema de se usar `IGNORE`em qualquer chave única, o efeito é o mesmo.

o `IGNORE` age tanto em violações de PK quanto a outras *constraints*, como o UNIQUE. Tanto é que você pode usar INSERT IGNORE se sua tabela tiver alguma *constraint* neste formato, inclusive:

```
alter table vote add constraint unique (ponto, endereço);
```

Em caso de violação da *constraint*, simplesmente o insert não acontece, e é gerado apenas um *warning* (que será ignorado sem problemas pela aplicação).

Só pra constar, lembre-se também que existe o `INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` que pode ser mais interessante em alguns casos (talvez não no seu exemplo, que me parece ser uma espécie de relação chave-valor).

**Nota:**

Se você pretende usar o `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, vai precisar de alguns cuidados. De acordo com a [documentação](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id):

> If you use INSERT IGNORE and the row is ignored, the LAST_INSERT_ID() remains unchanged from the current value (or 0 is returned if the connection has not yet performed a successful INSERT)

Que traduzindo livremente é

> Se você usar INSERT IGNORE e a linha for ignorada, o LAST_INSERT_ID() permanece como estava anteriormente, (ou 0 é retornado caso não tenha havido INSERT bem-sucedido)

Isto significa que você deve verificar se houve mesmo uma inserção real, pois caso não haja, o valor do LAST_INSERT_ID() pode estar contaminado e isto pode ser desastroso para a aplicação.

Talvez seja o caso de conjugar o resultado com o **[MYSQL_AFFECTED_ROWS()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-affected-rows.html)** para se saber se o valor retornado é utilizável de fato. Caso o valor retornado seja `0`, é sinal de que o ID retornado não corresponde à *query* que acabou de ser realizada.

Comment: É parece que o `IGNORE` não é a solução, minha esperança é que tivesse alguma forma de pegar o ID "duplicado" sem ter que fazer um `SELECT`. Valeu, praticamente já resolveu, só vou esperar até amanhã pra ver se aparece mais alguma resposta interessante.

Comment: @KaduAmaral o IGNORE é meio chatinho nesse aspecto. Cheguei a pensar se dava pra resolver com subquery, mas pensando bem, tem coisa que fica mais propensa à problemas de tanto que a gente quer simplificar. Quanto a esperar por mais respostas, acho sempre bom, pois incentiva o pessoal a postar coisas interessantes e complementar com informações novas.

Comment: Penso o mesmo tanto aos problemas quanto as respostas. :)